# Plotting an implicit function using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, gnuplot

How could one plot an implicit function, like `(x^2+y^2)^3-4x^2y^2` using TikZ?

I know `gnuplot` [supports them](http://newton.ph.unito.it/~moretti/gnuplot/implicit/solve-e.html), but they are drawn using a surface built from the function and intersecting the result with the `z=0` plane. How would one implement this work flow directly from TikZ? I know you can easily pass explicit functions to `gnuplot` but I don't want to split up the implicit function in its constituent parts if it's not necessary.

Of course, it's possible to plot in the `gnuplot` program and save the results, but I'm curious whether there is a more direct way :).

Comment: See also [gnuplot - Plotting an implicit function using pgfplots - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18359/plotting-an-implicit-function-using-pgfplots) for an example of gnuplot usage

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to use TikZ's front end to gnuplot.  If you use the `raw gnuplot` option you can pass a more complicated script to gnuplot to make it to what you want (rather than just plot a simple function).

I think it's almost impossible to do within TeX itself, which is after all a text processing system and not a computer algebra system.  You *could* use `pgfmath` (the math engine within TiKZ) to generate the surface points, and only plot the points where *z* is sufficiently close to 0.  But how would you connect these points?

Another method would be to use the function to write a differential equation and then implement Euler's method to plot a curve.  But that probably won't be as pretty as you want—assuming the curve is closed you would have to guess-and-check to make sure you plotted enough to close the curve and not too much to overlap.

There might also be a LuaTeX option but I don't know anything about that.

This particular curve is highly singular so first-stab TeX efforts probably wouldn't be very successful here.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should've been more clear, *any* solution was good but I was looking/hoping for something like `raw gnuplot`. I am trying it as we speak, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood.  I reworded my answer so it doesn't assume that attitude.

Comment: It kinda works now, `gnuplot` returns an impression of the implicit curve. The problem is that `raw gnuplot` returns the samples and TikZ just connects the dots. But I guess that's worth a follow-up question :).

Comment: This curve can be parametrized; maybe that makes your life easier.

Comment: Of course it's _possible_ within TeX, but I agree that it's probably inappropriate to attempt this since it would be way too slow.

Answer (score 16):

With PSTricks (If you don't mind to make a try):

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
  \psaxes{<->}(0,0)(-1.5,-1.5)(1.5,1.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \psplotImp[
    linecolor=red,
    stepFactor=0.1,
    algebraic,
    ](-1.5,-1.5)(1.5,1.5){(x^2+y^2)^3-4*x^2*y^2}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This blog post explains how to plot an algebraic curve using `raw gnuplot`

http://pbelmans.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/howto-draw-algebraic-curves-using-pgftikz/

I didn't try it, but it looks cool!

Comment: That's actually my own post discussing how to do this, and produce plots that don't suffer from the bug discussed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4745/how-to-use-the-results-of-raw-output-to-create-a-smooth-plot. Nowadays I think `pgfplots` supports some feature to do this without hacking things.