# Fun unicode characters with pandoc

Tags: unicode, pandoc

Silly question: I want to use a heart (♥) character in my presentation.

I'm already using xelatex as engine so it doesn't complain for the character itself but it doesn't render it. Just a blank space where the character should be.

Here is the snippet of the offending code:

```
    (Celery + RabbitMQ) ♥  Django
```

Notice that I'm using markdown for the input format.

This is how I make the pdf

```
pandoc -t beamer --latex-engine=xelatex \
    in.md -oout.pdf --slide-level=2
```

I'm new to pandoc and latex in general.

♥ Thanks ♥

Comment: Maybe you need this : http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9643/9467

Comment: Great! used `$\heartsuit$` instead of ♥ and it worked great. If you put that as an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: You should post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can see what font you are using.

Comment: Could [`newunicodechar`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newunicodechar) help?

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the edit, so why the bitter remark in the edit reasoning?

Comment: Maybe a knee jerk reaction. At the expense of getting meta: I just hate the trend to gain points nitpickingly editing questions on all SE sites. Sorry for being rude anyway.

Comment: Oh, we are kind of hiding in this obscure corner of SE. It's very easy to get rep here so people don't bother with 2 points. Besides, we have the amazing lockstep who is the edit/tag master (probably will visit this question too, check his edit stats :P). Just a reminder *Not upvoting* is preferred over *Downvoting*, hence less hassle and moar fun. If you see a question stuck at -1, it means that there is something seriously wrong about that question so we don't downvote more than -1. Other than that it's a pretty relaxed place.

Comment: Will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you need [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9643/9467).

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{arev}
\begin{document}
$\heartsuit$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just needed to use the latex sintax in the document. Time to learn some more latex. I'm loving pandoc.

Answer (score 9):

If you want a tikzsolution this works

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\heartz}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.01]
\draw[fill=black,thick,domain=0:2*pi,variable=\t,samples=100] %
plot ({16*sin(\t r)^3} , {13*cos(\t r) - 5*cos(2*\t r) - 2*cos(3*\t r) - cos(4*\t r) });
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\heartz 
\end{document}
```

This code was a result from a small discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5878921#5878921), thanks to percusse.

[image: Parametric equation for an heart.]

Comment: For the current `scale` and `samples` values, there is a glitch at the bottom corner. Increasing either one can get rid of such a glitch.

Answer (score 8):

The following works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XITS}

\begin{document}
♥ 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just another fun stuff with PSTricks. Compile the given code with `xelatex` because the code use JPEG image with which `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` sequence cannot work.

### User Defined Data

```
\def\Rows{5}
\def\Columns{5}
\def\Filename{tutuca.jpeg}%{example-grid-100x100pt}
\def\Scale{1.45}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

### Complete Code

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-func}

% user defined data
\def\Rows{5}
\def\Columns{5}
\def\Filename{tutuca.jpeg}%{example-grid-100x100pt}
\def\Scale{1.45}

% internal used data
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=\Scale]{\Filename}}

\def\func{%
    \psparametricplot{0}{2.5 .25 exp}{t^2  | 0.8*(sqrt(2.5-t^4)+t)}
    \psparametricplot{2.5 .25 exp}{0}{t^2  | 0.8*(-sqrt(2.5-t^4)+t)}
    \psparametricplot{0}{2.5 .25 exp}{-t^2 | 0.8*(-sqrt(2.5-t^4)+t)}
    \psparametricplot{2.5 .25 exp}{0}{-t^2 | 0.8*(sqrt(2.5-t^4)+t)}
}

\psset
{
    xunit=0.5\dimexpr\wd\IBox/\Columns\relax,
    yunit=0.5\dimexpr\ht\IBox/\Rows\relax,
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=500,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](-\Columns,-\Rows)(\Columns,\Rows)
    \rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
    \pscustom[unit=2cm,origin={0,-0.3},linecolor=yellow]{\func}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-\Columns,-\Rows)(\Columns,\Rows)
    \psclip{\pscustom[linestyle=none,linewidth=0pt,unit=2cm,origin={0,-0.3}]{\func}}
        \rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
    \endpsclip
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I should feel amused, flattered or disturbed :D

Comment: @tutuca: hopefully it is not the last one. :-)