# Algebraic curves in TikZ or Asymptote

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, asymptote

I want to draw algebraic curves in asymptote, but I do not know how this works. Has anyone an example?

If we want to plot for example `k[x,y]/\langle x^2+y^2-1\rangle`, where can I input the equation `x^2-y^2-1=0`? Here it is obvious that it is just a circle, but if we have several equations, this will not be so easy. Is there any command for this?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try to search this site for examples? E.g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz might be a good starting point. If things like that do not solve your problem, you should post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to illustrate where you are having problems exactly. This will raise your chances of getting suitable help significantly.

Comment: This might even be more suitable for your needs: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105570/how-to-plot-functions-like-x-fy-using-tikz

Comment: See also [Plot Tikz graph defined with two variables, ie 4=x^2+y^2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283097)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "several equations." If you are looking at algebraic curves in `k^2`, then every curve is a hypersurface and thus can be defined by a single equation.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps information on Asymptote with the `contour` module are on Stackexchange. Indeed Asymptote provides the `contour` module (also the excellent `smoothcontour3` module for implicitly defined 3D surfaces). 
For the question please consider the basic example

```
import contour;
import graph;
size(10cm);
real f(real x , real y)
{
  return x**3+y**3-3*x*y;
}
real [] c={-.5 , 0., .5}; // c should be an array
draw(contour(f,(-2,-2),(2,2),c));
xaxis("$x$",LeftTicks);
yaxis("$y$",RightTicks(trailingzero));
```

and the result

[image]

Other examples are available in the Asymptote documentation, with color, labels, or different pen...

O.G.