# Plotting functions with x and y on both sides in PGFPLOTS

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to plot a function in pgfplots using the addplot command. However, I can't solve the function for either of the variables I want to plot.

The equation is: 
$\frac{x}{1-.8^{10 - \frac{log(y - x)}{log(M)} - 1}} = y$

Is there a way that I can plot it even though variables appear on both sides?

I am plotting several other equations (all of which I can solve in terms of either x or y).

Comment: No.  You need to solve the equation first.  Unless you do a 3d plot of "left - right" and mark the zero contour.

Comment: If there is no closed form solution you can pre-calculate a table of x,y values and plot that.

Comment: A couple of examples of John's first suggestion: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283086/plot-tikz-graph-defined-with-two-variables-ie-4-x2y2/283097#283097 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18359/plotting-an-implicit-function-using-pgfplots/18384#18384