# Plotting an implicit function using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot, plot

What is the correct way to plot an implicit function using `pgfplots`? Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot+[mark=none] function[raw gnuplot] {
      set contour base;
      set cntrparam levels discrete 0.0;
      unset surface;
      set view map;
      set isosamples 500;
      splot exp(x)*cos(y)-1-x;
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is what the function looks like in `gnuplot`:

[image: expected result]

`pgfplots`, however, connects function's segments, which is unexpected:

[image: incorrect pgfplots result]

Comment: The development version of PGFPlots includes an `empty line` option that can be set to `jump` to get the desired behaviour. If you're using TeXLive, you can update PGFPlots through `tlmgr` by temporarily using the repository `http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/2010`.

Comment: @Jake: Consider posting this as an answer. Using the `empty line` option to allow interrupted plots works very well except gaps between segments become visible: http://i.imgur.com/8k3pp.png. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I'm afraid not, because that's just the data gnuplot generates (the gaps are also visible in the gnuplot screenshot in your question). If you increase the line width to `thick` and plot the contour for 0.003 instead of 0.0, it looks okay.

Comment: See also [graphics - Plotting an implicit function using TikZ - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4738/plotting-an-implicit-function-using-tikz) for other options/libraries of plotting implicit function in TeX.

Comment: The question explicitly asks for a pgfplots solution. Different libraries are irrelevant.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The development version of PGFPlots includes an `empty line` option that can be used to influence the behaviour. It is set to `jump` by default, which breaks the plot when an empty line is encountered. If you're using TeXLive, you can update PGFPlots through tlmgr by temporarily using the repository http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/2010.

The gap at the intersections is a numerical artefact introduced by gnuplot. It can't be fixed completely, but by plotting with a thicker line, and choosing a slightly different contour line to be plotted, it can be glossed over:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot +[no markers,
      raw gnuplot,
      thick,
      empty line = jump % not strictly necessary, as this is the default behaviour in the development version of PGFPlots
      ] gnuplot {
      set contour base;
      set cntrparam levels discrete 0.003;
      unset surface;
      set view map;
      set isosamples 500;
      splot exp(x)*cos(y)-1-x;
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplots/gnuplot contour plot]