# Part of function domain omitted using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

How would I plot the equation x^6+y^5cos(x)=1 and make a graph? I usually use `pgfplots`, but I am not sure how to work around the equals sign in this equation. When I solve for x and plot the function I get a result that differs from when I use Apple's Grapher application. Even when I extend the domain, the graph won't stretch beyond.
[image: Apple Grapher][image: Latex Result]

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
xmin=-3.5,
xmax=3.5,
ymax=3,
ymin=-2.5
]
\addplot[samples=100,domain=-3.5:3.5] {((1-x^6)/(cos(deg(x)))^.2};  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Plot `y` against `x`, rewriting the equation as `y=...`? `y` is just a function of `x` here, isn't it? What's the problem exactly?

Comment: @cfr, indicte roots of this equation? I'm guessing.

Comment: @Zarko Could be! Who knows?

Comment: Only the real values can be graphed, so y=((1-x^6)/cos(x))^0.2 from -\pi/2 to  \pi/2.  Note, while negative values are possible, ^0.2 doesn't like them.

Comment: If you have `gnuplot` available, you could use [this solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18359/plotting-an-implicit-function-using-pgfplots).

Comment: I edited the problem to further explain what is going on. I apologize for not being clear the first time.

Comment: PGFplots uses degrees instead of radians for trigonometric functions. Set `trig format plots=rad` to switch to radians

Comment: When I write cos(deg(x)), I still only get this first curve in the graph. Not the two in the corner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three problems.

1. `fpu` cannot handle **odd roots of negative numbers**. This causes a hole between 1, -1 and the respective nearby asymptotes.
2. The curve to draw is steep around the asymptotes, so **low sampling** make it wonky. If it's low enough the asymptotic behaviour disappears altogether.
3. The curve is drawn as a **continuous path**, so if there is a(n approximated) vertical asymptote of the kind you are drawing the jump from `-\infty` to `+\infty` gets drawn.

And there are three solutions.

1. A simple algebraic manipulation.
2. Increasing the sampling.
3. Giving `pgfplots` a cutoff on the `y` domain.

Here is the code, with numbers marking the solutions:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis} [ axis lines=center,
    xlabel=$x$, xmin=-pi,  xmax= pi,
    ylabel=$y$, ymin=-2.5, ymax= 4.5,
    restrict y to domain=-5:10,]          % (3)

  \def\f{(1-x^6)*sec(deg(x))}

  \addplot [samples=1000]                 % (2)
    {sign(\f)*pow(abs(\f),1/5)};          % (1)

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image: hop!]

Comment: I am still getting an error `unknown error: sign`.

Comment: That's a basic arithmetic function, see §89.3.1 of manual. You are using an outdated (<3.0.1) version of TiKz. Update it and it will compile.

Comment: How do I update it since I have `\usepackage{pgfplots}`?

Comment: Update your TeX distribution. If you want to keep it simple use algebra and write `abs(\f)/(\f)` instead of `sign(\f)`.

Comment: @PaoloBrasolin Wouldn't it be different (at least in general) when it's argument is 0? `sign(...)` returns 0, `abs(...)/...` errors. (AFAIK)

Comment: @SolomonUcko Yes, you are right. A correct custom implementation of the sign function would be along the lines of `\tikzset{declare function={sgn(\x) = greater(\x,0) - less(\x,0);}}` or something equivalent using the logical operators that are available in your `pgf` version.