# How to plot equation (not function) with TikZ

Tags: equations

I want to plot an **equation**, not a function, with Ti*k*Z. Is there any general way to realize it without calculation?

For example to plot the equation: `2x²-2xy+2y²=1` as follows

[image]

Comment: Place a \node, e.g. at (1.5, 0.4), and enter text in math mode, like `\node at (1.5, 0.4) {$2 x^2 ...$}; ` . That should do the job.

Comment: The pedestrian way: find the corresponding function, e.g. in wolframalpha.com `2x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2 = 1; solve (y)`: `y = 1/2 (x - sqrt(2 - 3 x^2)), y = 1/2 (x + sqrt(2 - 3 x^2))`

Comment: ...or you can use the plotting of implicit function through `gnuplot`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18359/plotting-an-implicit-function-using-pgfplots

Answer (score 0):

This ([standing on the shoulder of giants](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18384/38080)) works. There is a warning `Missing character: There is no`  `  `in font nullfont!` which I do not like at all, but I am not sure where it comes from.

You must compile with `-shell-escape` and have a recent `gnuplot` installed and reachable in your standard PATH.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      grid,
      xmin = -1, xmax=3,
      ymin=-1, ymax=1,
      ]
    \addplot +[no markers,
      raw gnuplot,
      thick,
      empty line = jump %
      ] gnuplot {
      set xrange[-1:3];
      set contour base;
      set cntrparam levels discrete 0.0;
      unset surface;
      set view map;
      set isosamples 500;
      splot 2*x*x-2*x*y+2*y*y-1;
    };
  \path (1,0.5) node[right, fill=white]{$2x^2-2xy+2y^2=1$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: implicit function plot through gnuplot]

Comment: Thank you so much!